# Is there a canonical way to tell if a process is in an MLE job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

In MLE instances the `HOSTNAME` env variable has `"mle-"` as a substring. Is this going to stay the same going forward? I need a standard way to determine if the process is part of an MLE job in order to set up the correct environment. As an example, in a GCE instance I can check that the `DATACENTER` env variable is `"gcp"` in order to set up the relevant environment for GCE - I am looking for the best way to do something similar for MLE.

Comment: could you explain a little more? Where are you seing the "mle-" prefix? I don't understand what do you want to achive and what question you have. Thanks!

Comment: I have a process that I want to run in multiple environments - say locally, GCE, MLE. I want the process to be able to tell which of these environments it is currently running in in order to trigger different behavior depending on the environment. I need a consistent way to check which of these environments the process is currently in - for example, if it is in GCE the environment variable DATACENTER will be set to "gcp". One idea I had for MLE is that I noticed when testing that the HOSTNAME environment variable contains the substring "mle-". However I don't know if this is always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running on Cloud Machine Learning Engine, the service sets the [TF_CONFIG environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/distributed-training-details), with a property: "environment": "cloud".